# API get request not resolving in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhe7p.png)

I'm wondering if it's because it's trying to access two IPs? Sorry if this is a noob question but when I hit my API I built in postman or even if I just throw the get request url into any browser it will return the JSON data. Kind of stuck as to why it will not resolve for me.

```
const app = document.getElementById('root')

const logo = document.createElement('img')
logo.src = 'logo.png'

const container = document.createElement('div')
container.setAttribute('class', 'container')

app.appendChild(logo)
app.appendChild(container)

var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', '18.220.177.84:8080/election_results?state=Ohio&year=2016&county=Cuyahoga', true)
request.onload = function () {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach((election_results) => {
      const card = document.createElement('div')
      card.setAttribute('class', 'card')

      const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
      h1.textContent = election_results.county

      const p = document.createElement('p')
      election_results.candidate = election_results.candidate.substring(0, 300)
      p.textContent = `${election_results.candidate}...`

      container.appendChild(card)
      card.appendChild(h1)
      card.appendChild(p)
    })
  } else {
    const errorMessage = document.createElement('marquee')
    errorMessage.textContent = `Gah, it's not working!`
    app.appendChild(errorMessage)
  }
}

request.send()
```

is it because i'm using a xml http request?

Comment: GIve detailed information about your API along with the required code.

Comment: i added my code.. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently mixing two separate IP adresses in your Postman GET call.

The first one is just local host (`127.0.0.1:5500`) and the second one is the actual server you are trying to reach (`18.220.177.84:8080`)

Your GET call should only hit (`18.220.177.84:8080`) (remove the first part, local host)

Comment: see above.. i added my code snippet. is it because i'm making an http request?

Answer (score 0):

The URL parser considers `18.220.177.84:8080` to be part of the *path* of the URL. Prepend it with `//` (and optionally a *scheme* like `https` to change the protocol) to let the parser know that this is the *authority* (*host* + *port* in this case) of the URL.

Comment: this worked! thank you! but i am now getting this message.."Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://18.220.177.84:8080/election_results?state=Ohio&year=2016&county=Cuyahoga. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

Comment: This is a security mechanism. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is with your code where you are making a get request to an URL without mentioning the protocol. Use HTTP or HTTPS whichever is required before the URL. So the URL will be,

`https://18.220.177.84:8080/election_results?state=Ohio&year=2016&county=Cuyahoga`

Hope this will solve your problem.

Now coming to your second problem regarding the CORS error. Basically, CORS or Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is a standard that allows a server to filter specific cross-origin requests while rejecting others. In your case, your request is blocked or rejected by the server. So to solve this issue,

1. If you have access to the server, allow your origin for cross-origin requests made from your origin. You can do that by settings, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <Your origin>`. For example, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000`. You can whitelist any origin by specifying
   `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, though I will highly recommend you not to do it.
2. You can use a proxy server for requests. Go through this [link](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/#documentation) for more info.
3. Use a plugin like [Moesif Origin & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-US) though it will only work on your browser and can be used only for development. (Not recommended)